Populating a MS Form from elements of a Sharepoint List with Power Automate on a scheduled basis
I have a Sharepoint list with dates and information. On specific dates, I would like to populate an existing request form (MS Form) with data from the Sharepoint List.
I think Power Automate can do the trick with automated workflow, but I have mostly seen how MS forms can populate a list, not the other way around.
Thanks for your help.

They can’t be populated programmatically. It’s a short coming of the product.

With the Forms API you have some options to manipulate the questions of your form. In this thread I have demonstrated how to update/PATCH the options of a choice question: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Autofill-question-in-MS-Forms-with-Power-Automate/m-p/2687472/highlight/true#M301723
